# Kubuntu 22.04 - Japanese input fcitx fails to configure

Tags: kubuntu, kde, input-method, japanese, fcitx

With a fresh build of 22.04, I get this message when I click configure:

> You're currently running KDE, but KCModule for fcitx couldn't be found, the package name of KCModule is usually kcm-fcitx or kde-config-fcitx. Now it will open config file with default text editor

I have confirmed that I have kde-config-fctix installed.

When I have read other posts, the solution is to use ibus, and I am not a fan of using that, or it suggest to use a package that is now a newer version, and that too is installed.

I have been following [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/byugan/how_to_install_japanese_input_in_linux_tutorial/) with installs of Kubuntu 20.04.  It also had worked after I had upgraded several computers to 22.04.

I am hoping to see if anyone else has come across this and found a fix.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Try `sudo apt install fctix5-mozc` 22.04 comes with Wayland and fctix5 is compatible.

Comment: Hello, This was ii :)  edit  sudo apt install fcitx5-mozc.  Once installed I was able to enter the config mode and add in the input.  Thank you

Comment: @SadaharuWakisaka's answer fixed it for me, but it has a typo, the correct command is: `sudo apt install fcitx5-mozc`